# Unity2D-How to restore hearts after destroying them when Player gets hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am using Destroy(Corazones[0].gameObject); to destroy 5 hearts in an array, but I need to restore them when the player gets another heart. I already have the collider that increases lives +1 and it works, but I do not know how to respawn the heart that represents that life.

The hearts get destroyed when the player gets Hit(); but I also need for the hearts to get restored with Vida(); which increases the live +1

Thanks for your help!
[This is the way the hearts look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsW5N.png)

My code uses spanish words.
PD: I know my code is a mess, but works for the other stuff.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DixonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PildoraPrefab;
    public float Speed;
    public float JumpForce;
    public AudioClip Golpe;
    public AudioClip Salto;
    public AudioClip Muerte;
    public AudioClip Caida;
    public GameObject[] Corazones;
  



    private Rigidbody2D Rigidbody2D;
    private Animator Animator;
    private float Horizontal;
    private bool Grounded;
    private float LastShoot;
    private int Health = 5;
    public bool YaSono = false;

    [Header("IFrame Stuff")]
    public Color flashColor;
    public Color regularColor;
    public float flashDuration;
    public int numberOfFlashes;
    public Collider2D triggerCollider;
    public SpriteRenderer mySprite;
    float timer;
    bool invencible = false;
    


    private void Start()
    {
        Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer <= 0)
        {
            invencible = false;
        }


        Horizontal = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (Horizontal < 0.0f) transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        else if (Horizontal > 0.0f) transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);




        Animator.SetBool("Caminar", Horizontal != 0.0f);

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down * 0.5f, Color.red);

        if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 0.5f))
        {
            Grounded = true;

        }
        else Grounded = false;




        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Grounded)
        {
            Jump();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && Grounded)
        {
            Jump();
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && Time.time > LastShoot + 0.25f)
        {
            Shoot();
            LastShoot = Time.time;
        }
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Shoot") && Time.time > LastShoot + 0.50f)
        {
            Shoot();
            LastShoot = Time.time;
        }

        /*  if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Vertical") && Time.time > LastShoot + 0.50f)
          {
              Shoot();
              LastShoot = Time.time;
          }*/


        if (transform.position.y <= -2)
        {
            Fall();

        }

        




    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(Horizontal * Speed, Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        Rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce);
        Camera.main.GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(Salto);
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        Vector3 direction;
        if (transform.localScale.x == 1.0f) direction = Vector3.right;
        else direction = Vector3.left;

        GameObject pastilla = Instantiate(PildoraPrefab, transform.position + direction * 0.40f, Quaternion.identity);
        pastilla.GetComponent<Pastilla>().SetDirection(direction);
    }



    **public void Hit()
    {
        
        Health -= 1;
        if (Health > 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FlashCo());
        }
        if (Health < 1)
        {
            Destroy(Corazones[0].gameObject);
            
        }
        else if (Health < 2)
        {
            Destroy(Corazones[1].gameObject);
           
        }
        else if (Health < 3)
        {
            Destroy(Corazones[2].gameObject);
            
        }
        else if (Health < 4)
        {
            Destroy(Corazones[3].gameObject);
            
        }
        else if (Health < 5)
        {
            Destroy(Corazones[4].gameObject);
            
        }
        if (Health > 0)
        {
            Camera.main.GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(Golpe);
        }**




        if (Health == 0)
        {
            Camera.main.GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(Muerte);
            Animator.SetTrigger("Muerte");


            if (Grounded == false)
            {
                Rigidbody2D.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic;
                Rigidbody2D.gravityScale = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                Rigidbody2D.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Static;
            }



        }


    }


    public void Fall()
    {
        if (transform.position.y <= -1)
        {

            Rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * 60);

            if (!YaSono)
            {
                Camera.main.GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(Caida);
                YaSono = true;
            }


            Animator.SetTrigger("Muerte");

            Health = 0;
            Destroy(Rigidbody2D, 2);

            Destroy(Corazones[0].gameObject);
            Destroy(Corazones[1].gameObject);
            Destroy(Corazones[2].gameObject);
            Destroy(Corazones[3].gameObject);
            Destroy(Corazones[4].gameObject);

            Invoke("RestartLevel", 2);



        }
    }

   public void Vida()
    {

        
        if (Health >=5) { } else { Health += 1; }
      
    }



    public void Bounce()
    {
        Rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * 300);
    }

    void Invencible()
    {
        timer = 1;
        if (timer > 0)
        {
            invencible = true;
        }
    }


    private IEnumerator FlashCo()
    {
        int temp = 0;
        triggerCollider.enabled = false;
        while (temp < numberOfFlashes)
        {
            mySprite.color = flashColor;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(flashDuration);
            mySprite.color = regularColor;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(flashDuration);
            temp++;
        }
        triggerCollider.enabled = true;
    }

    private void RestartLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

    


   

    


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Destroy(Corazones[0].gameObject)` you could use `Corazones[0].gameObject.setActive(false)` or simply `Corazones[0].setActive(false)` since the array already contains `GameObjects`.

This would preserve the `GameObject` while all of its components and children would be inactivated including its `Renderer` which would make it disappear.

Then later when you need it you could reactivate it using `Corazones[0].setActive(true)`.